# Set limit to re-connect attempts in MQTTjs?

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I maintain an application which uses MQTT.js in the browser to communicate with remote devices.

Some customers attempt to use the application behind firewalls that disable websockets, causing thousands of reconnect errors. Our error monitoring tool will often throttle error reporting because of the high volume of errors generated by MQTT.js (some users will leave the app open for hours after a connection failure).

Is there a way to set limits on reconnect attempts in MQTT.js?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I am also trying to implement a limit on number of retries to the MQTTjs.

Comment: @ShivamYadav Unfortunately I did not.